# PyQt5 - Dialog not closing via push button

Tags: python, pyqt5

Im having trouble getting my cancel button to close the dialog for a simple login app.

Im going round in circles trying to figure this out but I keep getting unknown "attribute errors".

I used pyuic5 to generate the ptyhon code for the ui and then copied over that portion to the end of main.py

This part fo the code looks different to other examples ive seen on the web

Any advice?

Login_Dialog.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_loginDialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, loginDialog):
    loginDialog.setObjectName("loginDialog")
    loginDialog.resize(400, 300)
    self.newuser_pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(loginDialog)
    self.newuser_pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 230, 75, 31))
    self.newuser_pushButton.setObjectName("newuser_pushButton")
    self.login_pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(loginDialog)
    self.login_pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 230, 75, 31))
    self.login_pushButton.setObjectName("login_pushButton")
    self.cancel_pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(loginDialog)
    self.cancel_pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 230, 75, 31))
    self.cancel_pushButton.setObjectName("cancel_pushButton")
    self.username_LineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(loginDialog)
    self.username_LineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 60, 201, 31))
    self.username_LineEdit.setObjectName("username_LineEdit")
    self.password_LineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(loginDialog)
    self.password_LineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 110, 201, 31))
    self.password_LineEdit.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
    self.password_LineEdit.setObjectName("password_LineEdit")
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(loginDialog)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 70, 91, 16))
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(loginDialog)
    self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 120, 47, 13))
    self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

    self.retranslateUi(loginDialog)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(loginDialog)

def retranslateUi(self, loginDialog):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    loginDialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("loginDialog", "Login"))
    self.newuser_pushButton.setText(_translate("loginDialog", "New User"))
    self.login_pushButton.setText(_translate("loginDialog", "Login"))
    self.cancel_pushButton.setText(_translate("loginDialog", "Cancel"))
    self.label.setText(_translate("loginDialog", "Username (Email)"))
    self.label_2.setText(_translate("loginDialog", "Password"))
```

main.py

```
import sys
import Login_Dialog
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from Login_Dialog import Ui_loginDialog



class ui(Login_Dialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ui, self).__init__()
        self.cancel_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.reject)

    def reject(self):
        self.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    loginDialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_loginDialog()
    ui.setupUi(loginDialog)
    loginDialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has the following errors:

- Login_Dialog refers to a .py file, it is not a class so you can not inherit it.
- Qt Designer only provide a design class that serves to fill a widget, it is not a widget. PyQt recommends creating a new widget and using the class provided by Qt Designer to fill it out.
- reject is a `QDialog` method so you could connect it directly that closes the window without using `close()`

With all the above, your code should be as follows:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from Login_Dialog import Ui_loginDialog

class ui(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_loginDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ui, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.cancel_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.reject)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = ui()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thank you very much. i am new to python and pyqt so this helped enormously. However I am still getting and exception:

    `code` File "main.py", line 11, in on_clicked
        self.rejected()
    TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable

Is this due to it being a native Qt signal that cannot be used in pyqt5?

Comment: @Hellbound_TKR sorry, copy a different code, and update my answer. If that answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it check the [tour]